# In pl/sql how can I execute a select statement stored in CLOB type of field?

Tags: plsql, clob

In Oracle DB, I have a large select staetment with lots of joins and cases that is stored in a CLOB field in one of my tables.
How can i execute this statement from the CLOB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` syntax.
Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id number, largedata clob);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'select name from v$database'); 
commit;
select * from test;
```

[image]

```
DECLARE
l_sql clob;
l_result VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT LARGEDATA INTO l_sql FROM TEST;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql INTO l_result;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
END;
/
```

Output is the DB name.

Comment: Hint: You got to have at least 11g for clobs and execute immediate.

Comment: [What?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) [Says who?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm#i287903)

Comment: Compare:
[10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm): It must be of type CHAR or VARCHAR2, not NCHAR or NVARCHAR2.
[11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/executeimmediate_statement.htm): Its type must be either CHAR, VARCHAR2, or CLOB.

Comment: Gotcha. I really thought you were suggesting `execute immediate` and `CLOB didn't exist in 10g. :)